# Is it possible to define a syntax-rules macro in Common Lisp

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, syntax-rules

I learned that it is easy to define a small macro in scheme by `syntax-rules`.
Is it possible to define a `syntax-rules` macro which will return a list can be read by `defmacro` in Common Lisp?

Which might work like this:

```
(defmacro and (&rest rest)
  (syntax-rules (rest) ()
    ((_)         t)
    ((_ x)       x
    ((_ x y)     (if x (if y y nil) nil))
    ((_ x y ...) (if x (and y ...) nil))))
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/pattern_matching.html)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? It's just pattern matching.

Comment: @Barmar such macro would need to know of lexical bindings, but `boundp` only works on global ones. You wouldn't know which variable to gensym and which refer to lexical bindings.

Comment: Yes, making it hygienic is a separate problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tim Bradshaw's [`destructuring-match`](https://tfeb.github.io/dsm/) is intended to make this kind of pattern matching easy in macros: it is a combination of `case` and `destructuring-bind`, so the key of each clause has the syntax of a destructuring lambda list.  There are several other pattern matching systems for CL, but this one explicitly is aimed at writing macros: it's not a general data structure matching tool, just a generalised version of `destructuring-bind`.

It comes with a little example macro (itself written using `destructuring-match` as well as expanding *into* something which uses `destructuring-match`!) called `define-matching-macro`, in which you can write a version of `and`, here called `et`.  I think the following two macros are correct but I have not thought much about them.

```
(define-matching-macro et
  "This is meant to be AND"
  ((_) 't)
  ((_ x) x)
  ((_ x . more ) `(if ,x (et ,@more) nil)))
```

You can alternatively just use `destructuring-match` in an ordinary `defmacro` macro.  Here I am not using `&whole` to get the whole form so we don't have to bother with the `car` of the form:

```
(defmacro et (&rest forms)
  "This is also meant to be AND"
  (destructuring-match forms
    (() 't)
    ((x) x)
    ((x . more) `(if ,x (et ,@more) nil))))
```

Notes:

- `destructuring-match` uses symbols whose name is `"_"` as blanks the same way Scheme does, so you don't need to declare them ignored, they are all distinct from each other, and in fact you may not refer to them in the body of the clause; but it does not do Scheme's `x ...` thing at all, so you just need to use dotted lambda lists or `&rest` or whatever you prefer;
- these are not hygienic macros, they're just pattern-matching macros;
- These are somewhat simpler than your example, but I think they are enough;
- your macro is not in fact safe, because `(if x x nil)`, as well as being redundant (it's just `x`) may evaluate `x` twice, which is unsafe.